# A better approach to refactor code when doing A/B Testing

Tags: refactoring, clean-code

I'm asked to refactor my component code to support A/B Testing.

What is the better approach:
1) Pass a boolean value to the methods and check for that flag inside the method body?

```
method(flag abTest):    
    if A_VERSION_ENABLED:
       // Do 'A' logic
    else
       // Do 'B' logic
```

2) Create dedicated methods for each version?

```
codeForATest()
codeForBTest()
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at the concept of Feature Toggle : http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). It allows you to swap out the behavior of a function or object on the fly by using interfaces. You specify how a method will be called, then have two or more versions that implement that interface. Then, you don't care about which one you're using in the code except upon initialization.